# firing a command through terminal in Ubuntu using Java Runtime.exec

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, terminal

This is fairly simple in Windows, but a little tricky in Linux. I am using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c", "java -classpath /home/4/byz/Orc" });
```

where Orc is the class file with a main function.
But nothing happens. Are there any settings ? Am I doing something wrong ?

I wish the java program to run in the terminal.

### EDIT

Here is the solution:

```
        String[] cmdArray = {"gnome-terminal","java -classpath /home/r/byz/ Orchestrator"};

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So basically, we have to use gnome-terminal ..

Comment: No surprises the command `java -classpath /home/4/byz/Orc` is incomplete. If you want to run a java Class, you will have to mention that at the end of `java` command. Did you try something like `java -classpath $CLASSPATH:/home/4/byz/ Orc` - note the space before `Orc`

Comment: i just tried your sugesstion, it didnt work :(

Comment: how do you run `Orc` from commandline?

Comment: i go to the folder containing the class file using `cd byz` and then I am doing  `r@r-desktop:~/byz$ java Orc`

Comment: or I use `java -classpath /home/r/byz Orc`

Comment: actually I havent been able to simply start the terminal using the Java Runtime.exec(). I think thats the problem.

Comment: @ringbearer On my system `gnome-terminal` starts the terminal. So i think I have to use this rather than `/bin/bash` in the command ? Since I want the gnome terminal to open and not the bash ?

Comment: @retun0,why dont you add an answer to the question then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is already resolved, however I'll post an answer:

How to Run:

```
executeCommand(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "java -classpath /home/4/byz/Orc"});
```

Method:

```
public String executeCommand(String[] cmd) {
    StringBuffer theRun = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            theRun = output.append(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        reader.close();
        process.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
        return theRun.toString().trim();
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: so i guess you are not only running the command, but also reading the output the command generates ? Please let me know if this is indeed the case. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I've used this in one of my apps before. It works great for returning output :)